# Hello! I'm struggling with trying to get a while loop to work

Tags: python

```
    op = {}
    while op != "+" or "-" or "x" or "/":
        op = str(input("Type in an expression: "))
        print("Invalid")
```

Output

```
    Type in an expression: +
    Invalid
    Type in an expression: -
    Invalid
    Type in an expression: /
    Invalid
    Type in an expression: x
    Invalid
    Type in an expression:
    // this bit is the return i get when running the code
```

This is a simple calculator that allows the user to choose an operator type based on input. I've added the bit of code, and what it returns when I run it. No error messages at all. Any help to get this to work will be greatly appreciated. Also, tell me of any better ways I can improve this piece of code. Thanks so much!

Comment: `op != '+' or '-'` doesn't group the way you think it does. It is not `op != ('+' or '-')`, it is `(op != '+') or ('-')`, and the latter is always true.

Comment: Could you explain? Or tell me how i can make this work?

Comment: `op != '+' or op != '-' or ...`, or else `op not in '+-x/'`

Comment: This is mainly due to operator precedence. https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/precedence-associativity 
Here != executes first it will return true or false depend on input then if you put or with any string it will return True . While loop will not end. It will become infinity

Comment: ahh thanks for your explanation. I have a question though, where is the true/false variable stored in? or is it even a variable?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do multiple comparisons at once - you would have to specify the `op !=...` bit repeatedly: `while op != "+" and op != "-" and op != "x" and op != "/":`

if you're trying to check if something is within a list of options, you can do that directly:

```py
while op not in ("+", "-", "x", "/"):
    op = str(input("Type in an expression: "))
    print("Invalid")
```

Comment: Similar output as the code in question

Comment: I have never used those statements before, but they seem to work as intended :)

Answer (score 1):

```py
op = str(input("Type in an expression: ")) # Ask for expression
while op not in ["+", "-", "x", "/"]: # Whilw op does not belong to this list, which mean that op is not any element form this list.
    print("Invalid") # Print invalid 
    op = str(input("Type in an expression: ")) # ask the person to input the operator again, till they correctly input an operator.
```

Here is something that should work with explanatory comments

The first line is needed because when you run the first iteration of the while loop, it first prints invalid before even asking for the operator.
If you reversed the statements, and put `op = str(input("Type in an expression: "))` before `print("Invalid")`, then It will first ask for an operator and then even if it is correct, it will print Invalid, before checking whether it is correct, thats why we need the first statement.

Comment: oH wow, this seems to work the best! Im not quite understanding how adding that extra line of input at the start managed to fix the issue, but thanks you! I'll try to understand it.

Comment: and thanks for telling me about the "not" and "in" statements. I never knew how to really use them.

Comment: Read my edit. Let me know if you need any more help. Cheers!